# How to ponysay multiline messages?

Tags: command-line, bash

When I am running `phpunit` I get a multiline response:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c tests/phpunit_no_code_coverage.xml --filter=Ncl
PHPUnit 4.1.6-6-g43914fa by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from tests/phpunit_no_code_coverage.xml

.

Time: 2.63 seconds, Memory: 21.50Mb

OK (1 test, 40 assertions)
```

Now I want the message to appear in a [ponysay](https://github.com/erkin/ponysay) bubble:

```
ponysay `./vendor/bin/phpunit -c tests/phpunit_no_code_coverage.xml --filter=Ncl` -W 220
```

This distorts the outpout, as phpunit's content is now on one line:

```
PHPUnit 4.1.6-6-g43914fa by Sebastian Bergmann. Configuration read from tests/phpunit_no_code_coverage.xml . Time: 2.69 seconds, Memory: 21.50Mb OK (1 test, 40 assertions)
```

Or in picture:

[image: Screenshot of hour ponysay displays the whole message only on one line]

I want for the message to keep its line breaks. How can I do that?

Comment: I had a quick look at the source and I _think_ that no, it strips newlines from the input. Not 100% sure but it does look like it.